# getting touches in UIResponder API

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

So, UIResponder has methods like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

My question is, what's the difference between the `touches` parameter, and `[event allTouches]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All sets of *touches* are stored within *event*.

However, for convenience Apple separately provides the touch that **triggered** the touchesBegan method to be invoked as a parameter.

If you searched through [event allTouches] and compared them to the UITouch within [touches anyObject], you would find a match.